# When to try data upload again if first sending fails?

Tags: objective-c, ios, mobile, timeout, http-post

In my app (iOS) data upload (http post) sometimes fails (timeout) on bad networks (EDGE).

What is the best strategy for retrying?

Should i retry immediatly or should i wait for "better" network conditions?
How could that be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to handle this, but which you choose very much depends on your application, and how critical the data you're posting is:

1. Assuming you're doing this in the background (asynchronously), just keep retrying until it works - maybe up to a maximum number of times.
2. Inform the user and ask them if they want to try again (let them know they need a network connection).
3. Store a cache of all un-transmitted data and try again after a period of time, or on app restart or when the app is backgrounded.

There's no *best strategy* - it all depends on the use case for your app.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having first try as normal but when it fails, show a `UIAlertView` with message some thing like: "Couldn't connect to servers, do you want to try again". Place `Yes` and `No` button. And when user taps `YES`, give it another try.